# Python virtualenv unlinking python and module pyc files

Tags: python, virtualenv, audit

I setup a python virtualenv.  The folder is protected from writing by non-root users.

When in the virtualenv I get some odd behavior.

If I just start python, the system audit log way have an entry showing I attempted to unlink the virtualenv python site.pyc file.

If I then run something like "import numpy", I will then get a slew of audit messages saying I tried to unlink all the .pyc files in the virtualenv python site-packages folder related to numpy.

If I run the native python (not in the virutalenv) I do not get any of these audit messages.

The really strange thing is that I have two "identical" systems.  Same redhat package set, same virtualenv folder, same audit rules.  However on the other system, I don't get the unlink messages in the audit.

I'd appreciate any advice on how I might track down the cause of this

Comment: This is normal behaviour when the pyc files are older than the py files.

Comment: The dates looked the same (to the minute at least).  Just in case, I reran as root so the pyc files are now definitely newer.  However when I run as a normal user, it still attempts to rewrite the pyc files.